# Pandas - transform series of dicionaries into series of dicionary values

Tags: pandas

After applying `pd.Series` to one dataframe column, like so:

```
df_pos = df_matches.col.apply(pd.Series)
```

I ended up with:

```
0  {'macro': 'GOL', 'macro_position': 'Goalkeeper'}
1  {'macro': 'DEF', 'macro_position': 'Defender'}
```

Now I need to turn it into this dataframe:

```
    macro    macro_position
0     GOL        Goalkeeper
1     LAT          Defender
```

---

**EDIT**:

None of the answers below work. If I do:

```
out = list(df_pos.values)
```

I get a list of strings of dictionary syntax:

```
...
array(["{'macro': 'ATA', 'macro_posicao': 'Ataque'}"],dtype=object),
...
```

Comment: ``data.apply(pd.Series)``

Comment: @sammywemmy I ha tried it. it does not work

Comment: i tried it with your shared data. the dictionaries are not embedded in quotes i bliv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
import ast

out = pd.DataFrame(df.col.apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())
Out[71]: 
  macro macro_position
0   GOL     Goalkeeper
1   DEF       Defender
```

Comment: worked. had never heard of that `ast` module. nice

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

#### using `.apply`

As mentioned by sammywemmy in the comments, by far the easiest approach is just to use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
import pandas as pd

sf = pd.Series([{'macro': 'GOL', 'macro_position': 'Goalkeeper'},
                {'macro': 'DEF', 'macro_position': 'Defender'}])

df = sf.apply(pd.Series)
```

This worked on my Python installation. Try executing the code above verbatim. Note, you do not need to write `.col` or anything like that. The `.apply` is a class method for `pd.Series`.

---

#### Using `pd.DataFrame` and dictionaries

[`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) can take a dictionary of dictionaries as an argument. So if you turn your `Series` into a dictionary, then you can just use `pd.DataFrame`, passing the dictionary as the `data` argument.

The one complication is that when converting a dict of dicts, it will interpret the inner dictionaries as the rows and the outer dictionaries as the columns. In your case, the rows of the series correspond to the *columns*, so if you just used `.to_dict()` naively, you would have the inner dictionaries as the columns, which is the wrong way around. The easiest way to fix this is just to transpose the `DataFrame` at the end, swapping rows and columns.

The result is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

sf = pd.Series([{'macro': 'GOL', 'macro_position': 'Goalkeeper'},
                {'macro': 'DEF', 'macro_position': 'Defender'}])

df = pd.DataFrame(sf.to_dict()).transpose()
```

Comment: The elements of your `Series` are *strings* of dictionary syntax... I'm not surprised these methods didn't work.

You'll need to convert the strings into actual dictionaries using `eval`. So try 
`df = sf.apply(eval).apply(pd.Series)`